# How a program know its output will be redirect?

Tags: linux, shell, command-line

When I use cURL, I Found it seems that cURL knew whether its own output will be redirect, or be input for another program.

Following are two different command:

```
curl http://www.google.com/
```

The output will be:

```
<HTML><HEAD>......blah, blah......</HEAD></HTML>
```

But if I use redirect or pipe, cURL will print its download status.

```
curl http://www.google.com/ | xargs echo
```

the output will be leading with:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   376  100   376    0     0   2729      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  5295
<HTML><HEAD>......blah, blah......</HEAD></HTML>
```

My question is: how cURL know whether its print will be redirect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`isatty(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/isatty) will tell you if a FD is connected to a TTY.